# Passing a bool condition to method which I can invoke when I need

Tags: c#

I need to pass in a predicate which I can invoke whenever I want (just like a delegate). I am trying to do something like this (I thought Predicate delegate would meet my needs):

```
MyMethod(Predicate,string> pred);
```

Called like: `MyMethod(s => s.Length > 5);`

I want to write the condition inline BUT invoke it when I want, just like a delegate. How could I do this>?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You would do it exactly like you wrote:

```
void MyMethod(Func<string, bool> method)  // Could be Predicate<string> instead
{
    // Do something
    // ...
    // Later, if you choose to invoke your method:

    if( method(theString) )
    {
      //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the following

```
bool MyMethod(Predicate<string> pred) {
  ...
  if ( pred("foo") ) { ... 
  }
}
```

Then

```
MyMethod(s => s.Length > 5);
```